# Why is there no ceil(float) in Java?

Tags: java, floating-point, integer

Suppose I would like to round up `float` to `int` in `Java`.
For instance,

```
roundUp(0.2) = 1
roundUp(0.7) = 1
roundUp(1.3) = 2
...
```

I would like to call `Math.ceil` and `Math.round` to do that but `java.lang.Math` does not provide `ceil(float)`. It provides only `ceil(double)`. So my `float` is promoted to `double` silently, `ceil(double)` returns `double` and `round(double)` returns `long` while I need to round up `float` to `int` (not `long`).

Now I wonder why `java.lang.Math` has only `ceil(double)` and does not have `ceil(float)`.

Comment: I note with some small amusement that the numbers in your examples are doubles, not floats!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can do:

```
value = (int) Math.ceil(value);
```

If you know that `value` is a float then you can cast the result back to `float` or `int`.

It makes no sense for the Java library to provide both `ceil(float)` and `ceil(double)` as all float arguments can be passed to the `ceil(double)` method with the same result.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: thanks, I've updated the answer as the question is indeed about obtaining an `int`.

Comment: I would like to avoid castings. It does not look safe.

Comment: In which case you may not way to turn it back into a `float` ;)

Comment: @Michael You cannot turn all possible `float` values into an `int` or `long` so it shouldn't look safe. ;) BTW `ceil(float)` would still have to return a `float` so it doesn't avoid any casting.

Comment: I mean that if `ceil(float)` had returned `float` I would have called `round(float)` to get `int` w/o any casting: e.g. `round(ceil(0.3f))`

Comment: “It makes no sense for the Java library to provide both ceil(float) and ceil(double) as all float arguments can be passed to the ceil(double) method with the same result.”  Then why DOES it make sense to have both `round(float)` and `round(double)` ?